# How to show two pdf in differents tabs from java

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Sorry for my poor english but I really want to show two pdf reports from jasper report at the same time in differents tabs on browser. I´m working with java jsf, primefaces. The principal idea is when the button is clicked show this reports in diferents tabs. I try to do this:

I have this in the Managed Bean:

```
        public void showReports() {  
                  RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("document.getElementById('fromGeneral:rep2').click();");
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("document.getElementById('fromGeneral:rep3').click();");
            }

    public void printReport(String name) {
            try {
                Map<String, Object> mapParametros = new HashMap<>();
                mapParametros.put("CORR", corr);
                printJasper(mapParametros, new File("/Jasper/Reports/" + name));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

  public void printJasper(Map<String, Object> reportValues, File fileJ) {

        ByteArrayInputStream input = null;
        BufferedOutputStream output = null;
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

        try {
            facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
            response = (HttpServletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();

            FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(fileJ);
            JasperReport compiledTemplate = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(file);

            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(compiledTemplate, reportValues, dataSourceP.getConnection());

            JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter();
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
            exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, out);
            exporter.setParameter(JRPdfExporterParameter.PDF_JAVASCRIPT, "this.print();");
            exporter.exportReport();

            input = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());

            response.reset();
            response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(out.toByteArray().length));
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"ticket.pdf\"");
            output = new BufferedOutputStream(response.getOutputStream(), Constants.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[Constants.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE];
            int length;
            while ((length = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                output.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            output.flush();

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            System.out.println(exception.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (output != null) {
                    output.close();
                }
                if (input != null) {
                    input.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                /* ... */
            }
        }
        facesContext.responseComplete();
    }
```

An this in my view:

```
<h:form>          
    <p:commandButton value="Show them" action="#{reportBean.showReports()}"/>
    <p:commandButton value="REPORT 1" id="rep1"  style="font-size: 25px; float:right;visibility: hidden;" action="#{reportBean.printReport("Report1")}" ajax="false" onclick="this.form.target = '_blank';"/>
    <p:commandButton value="REPORT 2" id="rep2"  style="font-size: 25px; float:right;visibility: hidden;" action="#{reportBean.printReport("Report2")}" ajax="false" onclick="this.form.target = '_blank';"/>
    </h:form>
```

But doesn´t work, it just show the second report. 
Help!. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found other way to solve it.

The method `showReports()` instead to click two buttons, this open two xhtml that each one has inside of `<h.form>` a remotecommand with autorun true, that show the reports. I don´t know if it´s the best way to do it, but It works.

Thanks for all your comments

Answer (score 0):

Try a hit using `p:commandLink` like i am using.

```
<p:commandLink id="PreviewR1"   value="Print Preview" ajax="false" action="#{reportBean.printReport("Report1")}" target="_blank" />
<p:commandLink id="PreviewR2"   value="Print Preview" ajax="false" action="#{reportBean.printReport("Report2")}" target="_blank" />
```

It will open the report 1 & 2 in separate browser tab while your original web page will remains the same.

Comment: Hello Sarz! Thanks for comment. But it doesnt work, it is still showing one report. :/

Comment: Try to use different method i.e. printReport1 printReport2 instead of taking args.

Comment: I did it too, and it still does not work, but I posted what I solve it. Thanks for your time answering.

Answer (score 0):

You just don't click the correct buttons:

```
public void showReports() {  
                  RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("document.getElementById('fromGeneral:rep2').click();");
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("document.getElementById('fromGeneral:rep3').click();");
            }
```

You're clicking on rep2 and rep3. rep3 doesn't exists, you need to click on rep1 instead. That should be the reason why only the 2nd report is shown.

Comment: Thanks lastresort for answering, my mistake! but i already fixed it, and still doesnt work.